# CSV Datasource in Subreport

Tags: csv, jasper-reports, subreport

I'm new to JasperReports and I have a big problem inserting Subreports from CSV. I've been looking for information for 3 days and can not understand what must I do.

I have a dataset named RB1 in csv format, that I need to import to JasperReports. In the main report I have no problems, I can import it and show fields as I want.

The problem arises when I need to insert a subreport with the same database.

I create another report named SUB_1, and link it to the database RB1 as if it was an usual report, and I put the variable COLUMN_0 to be shown in the details section. I previsualize it and it is OK.

I go back to the main report and drag the item SUBREPORT to the summary section and select "select an existing report". I choose the report SUB_1 -> NEXT

I select "use same JDBC connection used to fill the master report" -> NEXT

In the Dataset Parameters I clic ADD and write:

```
 PARAMETER NAME: COLUMN_0
 PARAMETER EXPRESSION: $F{COLUMN_0}
```

What I'm trying to do is to link the variable COLUMN_0 of the main report with the variable COLUMN_0 in the subreport.

Now, when I try to previsualize the report, the subreport does not show.

In the Properties of the Subreport I have:

```
EXPRESSION: "SUB_1"
PARAMETERS MAP EXPRESSION:
CONNECTION EXPRESSION: $P{REPORT_CONNECTION}
DATA SOURCE EXPRESSION:
```

What am I doing wrong? I guess that many things, but could not find any answer online with this in detail in a way that I can understand it.

Comment: Seems that no data is available in the subreport. Try changing `When No Data Type` to something different than the usual `No Pages`. Additionally, the iterator on the data could be at the very end (details are in the main report) and when Jasper switches to the subreport, the iterator has no data to deliver.

Comment: I just tried it again (what you said), changing the option of WHEN NO DATA TYPE to All Sections, no Detail, and I can see the subreport, but no the detail section (ie, I see the Title etc). The point then is that I have no data in the subreport? How to solve this? Thank you!!

Comment: Again, it could be that the main report has consumed all data already. You wrote that you use the `Summary` band. Here in the main report the field `$F{COLUMN_0}` should be `null`. So either put the subreport in the `Details` section if feasible or create a variable with COLUMN_0 (if only one row) and put it into a variable. Pass the variable to the subreport.

Comment: I tried it, I put the subreport in the Details section, but again I just see all except the details of the subreport, where I have some data. It seems that there is something in the connection to the subreport that is not working. Again thank you for the reply

Answer (score 0):

I solved the first part of my problem: I could print data in the subreports from the main report. Or better said, I could half-print some data.

I use an answer to the question I posted, to continue asking about this problem.

I have been thinking and looking for info and I think that the problem now could be because of the indices. The point is that when my subreport is used, there is some data that has been used by the main report, so the subreport seems not to work for the lines that were used by the main report. Is that possible?

If this is the problem, is there any way to make my subreports to work for all data and not just for the ones that are not used in the main report?

Thank you very much!!

I think I am really close to solve it thank to you :D:D